# Loading friends information quicker

Tags: php, sdk, facebook-opengraph

My app needs user's friends info (birthday, picture and name):

I use Graph API through the SDK (php).
I first request the friends ID via `api('/me/friends')` 
Afterwards I request the aforementioned information: `api('/id?fields=name,picture,birthday')`

To optimize speed I make the call in batch requests.

My problem is that it takes aprox 40 sec to load 530 friends, which seems to me a lot. I am using similar apps developed by other people and they load friends (the same info) in 9sec.

I was wondering if any of you know how I can request this info quicker or at least explain where this difference can come from.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making so many api calls, simply use the fql as-

```
$fql = "select uid,name,birthday_date from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me())";
$param  =   array(
                   'method'      => 'fql.query',
                   'query'       => $fql,
                   'access_token'=> ACCESS_TOKEN
                 );

$friends_arr = $facebook->api($param);
```

Get the path of the picture using:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/'.$FRIEND_ID.'/picture?type=TYPE
```

Comment: Thanks! Will give it a try and let you know the outcome tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing a preliminary load of data the first time into a local database so that you can use that for further information. It will be much faster to retrieve.

If you have many plugins on your page, it could slow down the result (using the like plugin, for example).

The time it takes to connect to Facebook (the latency) is generally out of your control so you could turn the request into an asynchronous request and show the user that it is loading during the process.